Data segmentation in Searchkit - grouping question
I would like to create a search, using data segments, that groups data. It's a similar question to this but I think not the same. Users have a single selection of A, B, C, D, E, F, G.  I want to create a search that does a 'group by' on this selection which shows them grouped differently: AC, B, DFG, E
When you add a data segment you can only 'AND' the selection criteria but not 'OR' otherwise that would work.  Is a way to achieve this re-grouping?
